# SQL CE 3.5 on Windows 2007 Failure to open SQL Server with given connect string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce

I create SQL CE 3.5 database dynamically in asp.net webservice. I can create tables, but when I try to use SqlCeRemoteDataAccess methods I get an error message: "Failure to open SQL Server with given connect string". Everything works fine in Windows XP, but when I publish it on production server Windows 2007 Server Standart it stops working. Connection properties are good. And rda works if call rda methods in mobile devices. I think that it should be something with a security, but why then rda works from mobile devices. Any ideas?

On server is installed SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 and SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 Server Tools. I tried ip address and a machine name in a connection string. A coonection string: "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=myPass;"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try a simpler connection string: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/03/snapshot-synchronization-with-sql.html